# Create form application with database included

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am currently working on windows form applications (Visual C++). I have connected to MySQL database and get/query data from that server. The problem is when i have to use application on other places then i have to install MySQL there too. Is there anyway through which i don't need to connect to external database server and include database in application itself?

Comment: You could incorporate the mysql installer within your application's setup project. But mysql is not really an embedded database. With .Net I would consider using ms sql ce instead.

Comment: i install ms sql ce, but couldn't find any help on using sql ce in .NET and C++, i just was able to connect to database from Data Connections but don't know how to work with it in programming.